# Ubuntu on tablet can move mouse, but can't click

Tags: 15.04, touchscreen, tablet, tap-to-click

I installed Ubuntu on a Lenovo Thinkpad Helix and it runs fine, except that I can't tap to click.

The mouse moves fine, but no click events are fired. The touchpad works fine; the problem is only with the touchscreen.

Are there any drivers I need to look into?

Answer (score 1):

In my particular case the `usbhid` kernel module was not automatically loaded.

I added it into the `/etc/modules` file to load it on boot and it works now.